# Smallest non-4-space-filling polytesseract?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, tiling

As a follow-up to [Smallest non-space-filling polycube?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142544/smallest-non-space-filling-polycube/4142557), what's the smallest polychoron produced by fusing tesseracts 3-face to 3-face which does not fill 4-space?

Comment: From the linked question about 3d, we know that all polycubes up to heptacubes fills 3-space and one octocube does not (the ring). There's one pentatesseract that is not the elevation of a pentacube, but it obviously fills 4-space, since it fits together with another copy to make a 2x2x2x2 tesseract. So I guess one just needs to check the non-elevated hexa-, hepta-, and octotesseracts as well as the elevated ring octotesseract to verify that the smallest non-filler again goes up from 3d to 4d, as would be expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the smallest polytesseract not able to fill 4-space has to be <s>at least a decatesseract, possibly larger!</s> **either an undecatesseract or a dodecatesseract** (updated after Edit 2)!

I updated my code in github: [whuts-solver](https://github.com/gepa71/whuts-solver) to make it work in higher dimensions (and optimized it to run much faster), and tried generating tilings with polytesseracts in the last couple days.

So far, it looks like there exists a 4d-space-filling tiling for all polytesseracts up to and including <s>nonotesseracts</s>decatesseracts! The individual results are in the github link in results/poly_4_x.

<s>I am now running the code for all decatesseracts, but this is running much slower, after one day it has processed around 50,000 of the around 850,000 possible decatesseracts (found a tiling for all of those so far). I will update when that run finishes, but looks like this will take some time...</s>

I could indeed have ignored the ones that get produced by elevating a polycube (except the ones that don't tile 3d-space), but this is a small percentage anyway, so I just let my code run on all beginning from pentatesseracts.

**Edit**

I came up with a dodecatesseract, which definitely does **not** tile 4-space (elevating the image below into 4d). Nothing would fit in the "hole" in the middle. That means, if my search through the decatesseracts finds a tiling for all of them (it is now around half way through and so far all work), the smallest non-4-space-filling polytesseract would be either an undecatesseract or a dodecatesseract. There are around 9 million undecatesseracts, so checking those would take quite some time. I did check the ones that get generated by removing one hypercube from the dodecatesseract in the picture (I thought if anything, these would be difficult to fill 4-space), and those can fill 4-space. Also, I run some code to check all undecatesseracts, whether there is any that obviously does not tile space, similar to the dodecatesseract (with a hole that can not be covered), but it looks there is none such.

**Edit 2**

My code finished running for all decatesseracts and found a 4-space filling tiling for each of them! I put all tilings in one file in my github under [results/poly_4_10_all.json.bz](https://github.com/gepa71/whuts-solver/blob/main/results/poly_4_10_all.json.bz2) (one big json file compressed with bzip2, containing a list of solution in the format previously used).

[image: dodecatesseract]

Comment: Interesting results! I am only not accepting this answer because no non-filler has been found yet. I should perhaps have stated it to ask whether the smallest non-filling polytess was larger than eight units (as in 3d), which you have now established, that it must be at least 10 units. Will be interested in the eventual results of the run.

Comment: Is there any point in focusing your search among decatesseracts on something that seems intuitively like a potential non-4-space-filler, like the elevation of the decacube consisting of a ring of eight with a branch of two more from a middle cube that "caps" the central hole?

Comment: I think the way you asked the question is better like this, with no explicit artificial limits and just leave it open-ended. It can remain unanswered, and if/when somebody finds a non-filler they deserve to get their answer marked as correct. Regarding focusing on intuitive potential non-fillers my code would only point out potential candidates, but the way it works it will never prove that a tiling is impossible, so the only meaningful statement it can produce is either that all decatesseracts can tile, or show some candidates to check in another way.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity I just checked the one you mentioned in your comment anyway (the 8 ring with a cap, elevated in 4d), it has been already processed and it has found a tiling of 4d space with three tiles in the basic pattern.

Comment: I figured narrowing it down to "11 or 12" was good enough for the acceptance... If you let your undecatesseract 4-space-filling finder run for a few weeks (seems like that's what it would be) and determine which is the case and come back and update this to settle it exactly, all the better. But even in that case, I don't think three terms 7,8,11... or 7,8,12,... is quite enough for submitting a sequence to the OEIS. :( Given the jump for 4-space, I imagine the minimum non-n-space filling poly-block is going to grow fairly rapidly.

Comment: Thanks for accepting! I am indeed running the code for all undecatesseracts, it is expected to take around a month still. I will update when done. So far, out of around 200k (2% of all) that I checked with primitive boxes consisting of 1,2,3,4,6 or 8 undecatesseracts, all but one succeeded (I am checking this one separately with different sized boxes). I have a feeling so far, that they will all be able to tile 4-space, but not sure if my code will be able to find all, for some the simplest tiling may just be too complex.

Comment: I am not updating the answer since I still don't have a definite answer, but I can share here an update of the progress: after going through all around 9 million undecatesseracts, there are now only 3 left for which I have not found a 4-space filling tiling yet (all 3 are 2d-flat and symmetric). I have checked these with primitive boxes consisting of 1,2,3,4,6,8 and 10 undecatesseracts, checking these now with 12 and later with 14 and 16 (even numbered boxes feel somehow more promising), though it gets increasingly slower with bigger boxes, so this is expected to take quite some time still.

Comment: @GeorgiosPapoutsis: Curious if this code ever finished, or if not what the three remaining candidates were!

Comment: No, sadly I stopped the search at some time going for vacation, and after I came back I never ended up continuing the search.
These are the three remaining candidates if somebody wants to give it a try, maybe optimizing a search for these specific shapes: [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4],[4,3],[4,4],[5,1],[5,2],[5,3]], [[1,1],[1,2],[1,6],[1,7],[2,2],[2,3],[2,5],[2,6],[3,3],[3,4],[3,5]], [[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[2,3],[3,3],[4,3],[5,3],[6,2],[6,3],[7,1],[7,2]].
If there is interest I can upload somewhere my solutions to all other 9M 11-tesseracts (it would be a 200MB file compressed).